# PostgreSQL - Replace HTML Entities

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, replace

I have just set about the task of stripping out HTML entities from our database, as we do a lot of crawling and some of the crawlers didn't do this at input time :(

So I started writing a bunch of queries that look like;

```
UPDATE nodes SET name=regexp_replace(name, '&#xe0;', 'à', 'g') WHERE name LIKE '%#xe0%';
UPDATE nodes SET name=regexp_replace(name, '&#xe1;', 'á', 'g') WHERE name LIKE '%#xe1%';
UPDATE nodes SET name=regexp_replace(name, '&#xe2;', 'â', 'g') WHERE name LIKE '%#xe2%';
```

Which is clearly a pretty naive approach. I've been trying to figure out if there is something clever I can do with the decode function; maybe grabbing the html entity by regex like `/&#x(..);/`, then passing *just* the `%1` part to the ascii decoder, and reconstructing the string...or something...

Shall I just press on with the queries? There will probably only be 40 or so of them.

Comment: You'll want to `VACCUM` aggressively if you're doing this, to avoid huge table bloat. Doing the text processing in a PL is by far the better approach as @SzymonGuz explains. It's possible in SQL using `substring` or `regexp_matches` and a replacement table, but it'll be slow and ugly.

Comment: thanks for the VACCUM tip, I shall look into that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a function using pl/perlu and use this module https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities

Of course you need to have perl installed and pl/perl available.

**1)**
First of all create the procedural language pl/perlu:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plperlu;
```

**2)** Then create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION decode_html_entities(text) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    use HTML::Entities;
    return decode_entities($_[0]);
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

**3)** Then you can use it like this:

```
select decode_html_entities('aaabbb&amp;.... asasdasdasd &hellip;');
   decode_html_entities    
---------------------------
 aaabbb&.... asasdasdasd …
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping not to have to jump into perl, but I guess a pure sql solution would be a little too much to ask for!

Comment: Well, it would be also very easy, however much longer than those 2 lines of perl code.

Comment: Requires apt-get install postgresql-plperl-9.1

Answer (score 6):

You could use xpath (HTML-encoded content is the same as XML encoded content):

```
select 
  'AT&amp;T' as input ,
  (xpath('/z/text()', ('<z>' || 'AT&amp;T' || '</z>')::xml))[1] as output
```

Comment: So far the theory, but this breaks on &ouml; Looks like a bug in the postgre-XML handling.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it took for me to get working on Ubuntu 18.04 with PG10, and Perl didn't decode some entities like `&comma;` for some reason. So I used Python3.

From the command line

```
sudo apt install postgresql-plpython3-10
```

From your SQL interface:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpython3u;

CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION htmlchars(str TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    h = HTMLParser() 
    if str is None:
        return str
    return h.unescape(str);
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```