# I want to escape HTML character entities in a string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, html-escape-characters

Say I have this string: `'<Hello World>'`,
I want to to be: `'&lt;Hello World&gt;'`.
Is there a way to do that in PostgreSQL 8.4?

```
SELECT '<Hello World>' AS smth
FROM smth_table
```

ColdFusion has a method called [XmlFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e62.html) which does exactly that.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong : you need to select `'<Hello World>' ` as `'&lt;Hello World&gt;'` including `'` ?

Comment: Did you look in the docs? They seem to be fairly comprehensive: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html. This would suggest the answer is "no". It's a bit of an situation-specific bit of functionality for a DB I think?

Comment: @Kevin what about this `select replace(replace('<Hello World>','<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;')` (_if this is you want then it's better to create a custom function in Postgres to do the job like in coldfusion's `XmlFormat(string, escapeChars)`_)

Comment: If you can use PL/Perl or PL/Python, you can create a function that uses their modules to do this. But usually it's not really the database's thing to do this kind of stuff. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145634/postgresql-replace-html-entities

Comment: Hi @SamiKuhmonen, I agree. This shouldn't be done with the DB, but in my case I am directly creating a CSV from a COPY TO.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest trying the PL/languages to do this, Pgsql internally doesn't have any functions for this and it's always better to use actually tested functions than to make your own. Been there, always forget some little thing...