# What does this xpath function mean?

Tags: postgresql, xpath

I'm trying to decode the URL characters such as "&amp" to "&", I found the code works in [PostgreSQL - Replace HTML Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145634/postgresql-replace-html-entities)

. The code is `(xpath('/z/text()', ('<z>' || 'AT&amp;T' || '</z>')::xml))[1] as output`.

I try to understand this code and read the document of it, but the only thing I found is the explanation of `xpath(xpath, xml [, nsarray])`. I'm a freshman on PostgreSQL, and I know the /z/ is like a tag. But what is the "||","[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145634/postgresql-replace-html-entities)" means? why should it use '/z/text()'.

If there have some links about that, it will very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: || is string concatenation '<z>' || 'AT&amp;T' || '</z>' is the same as '<z>AT&amp;T</z>

Comment: Your code says get the text that is a child of the z element starting at the root of the xml